# How to add something to gradle for other users?

Tags: android, gradle

How to add your own project to the `gradle` so other users can use it as a dependency? E.g.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.myDomain.myProject-v1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a library project. [See this](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html).
2. Push it to github. (Optional).
3. Publish it to [bintray](https://bintray.com/). [See this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You have to push it in a maven repo, private or public.
You can check for example the [bintray repo](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_centralrepositories.html#_jcenter) (`jcenter`)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Some Other Folder is a gradle project you could add something like the following to your settings.gradle file:

```
include ':module1'
project(':module1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Project B/Module 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it available in a repository. A very simple one is [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/).

- Host your lib on [Github](https://github.com/)
- Add JitPack in repositories
- Add the dependency `compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'`

Sample:

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
}
```

[Full documentation](https://jitpack.io/docs/)

Comment: This is the simplest & quickest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please you need to study about how to make library (module) on android studio, what is jcenter, what is maven center and also study about bintray.com.